# IOError: [pyAgrum] I/O Error: Stream states flags are not all unset

Tags: python, inference, bayesian-networks

I ran the following code in jupyter notebook. but there is this error: IOError: [pyAgrum] I/O Error: Stream states flags are not all unset.  is there a solution to solve it?

`gum.saveBN(bn,os.path.join("out","WaterSprinkler.bif"))`

```
with open(os.path.join("out","WaterSprinkler.bif"),"r") as out:
print(out.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes that there is a folder 'out' in which the bn will be stored. It looks like you haven't created this folder. If you create the 'out' folder in the working directory of the notebook and run it again, it should work.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: yes, if you create the folder 'out' where the file 'WaterSprinkler.bif' is saved, it should work.

Comment: It would help a lot if pyAgrum gave a more helpful error message for such a mundane and easily solvable problem.